# Netlogo: "expected a literal value" in a "ifelse" block

Tags: netlogo

I want to check if the turtle is a sheep or wolf, and set commands seperately. But Netlogo highlights the `set` and tells me

> expected a literal value

Here is edited code, I added more basic information and did some simplification for quick understanding.

```
breed [sheep a-sheep]
breed [wolves wolf]


sheep-own [SEnergy]
wolves-own [WEnergy]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-sheep 100
  ask sheep [set SEnergy 100]
  
  create-wolves 100
  ask wolves [set SEnergy 100]
  
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles[
    (ifelse
      is-a-sheep? [set SEnergy SEnergy - 1]
      is-wolf? [set WEnergy WEnergy - 1])
  ]
  tick
end
```

I've red the example in Netlogo dictionary

```
(ifelse boolean1 [ commands1 ] boolean2 [ commands2 ] ... [ elsecommands ])
```

Thus I think `[set SEnergy SEnergy - 1]` in my code is expected a **command**. Why Netlogo tells me a **literal value** is needed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your syntax for the is-a-sheep? and is-wolf? statements.  is-breed? takes a single argument, the identity of the agent you are testing.  Your code should therefore be

```
to go 
  ask turtles[
    (ifelse
      is-a-sheep? self [ set SEnergy SEnergy - 1 ]
      is-wolf? self [ set WEnergy WEnergy - 1 ])
  ]
end
```

Then each turtle is asking itself what it is.

Of course, you could just ask each agentset separately.

```
ask sheep [set SEnergy SEnergy - 1]
ask wolves [set WEnergy WEnergy -1]
```

Charles